# CodeCeptJs is it possible to parellel test with webdriver and appium?

Tags: webdriver, appium, codeceptjs

So i am trying to simultaneously test both desktop and mobile in parallel is it possible with codeceptjs or would i need to run one after the other?

this is my codecept config file :-

````
tests: './*_test.js',
output: './output',
multiple: {
 parallel:{
   // Splits tests into 2 chunks
   chunks:2,
   //Run all tests in chrome and firefox can add internet explorer 11 very slow though
   browsers: ['chrome', 'firefox']   //'internet explorer']
 }
},
helpers: {
 WebDriver: {
   url: 'http://localhost',
   browser: 'chrome',
   Appium: {
     app: '/path/to/app/foo.app',
     platform: 'iOS',
     desiredCapabilities: {
       deviceName: "iPhone 6",
       bundelId: "com.app.foo",
       automationName: "XCUITest",
       autoWebview: false,
       newCommandTimeout: 3600,
       platformVersion: "11.2",
       fullReset: false,
       noReset: true,
       locationServicesEnabled: true
       locationServicesAuthorized: true,
       calendarAccessAuthorized: true
 }
},
include: {
 I: './steps_file.js'
},
bootstrap: null,
mocha: {},
name: 'CodeCeptJs'
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but I learned by running with npm.

You must create scripts for each platform in the `package.json` file to override the helpers in`codecept.conf.js.` Comment out the helpers in the `codecept.conf.js` file.

Add the code below to your `package.json` file.

```
"scripts": {
"web": "codeceptjs run -c codecept.conf.js --override '{\"helpers\": {\"WebDriver\": {\"url\": \"<your_url>\", \"browser\": \"chrome\", \"host \": \"127.0.0.1\", \"port\": 4444, \"restart\": \"false\", \"windowSize\": \"1920x1680\", \"desiredCapabilities\": {\"chromeOptions\": {\"args\": [\"-disable-gpu\", \"-window-size=1200,1000\", \"-no-sandbox\"]}}}}}'--steps",
"ios": "codeceptjs run -c codecept.conf.js --override '{\"helpers\": {\"Appium\": {\"app\": \"/path/to/app/foo.app\", \"platform\": \"iOS\", \"desiredCapabilities\": {\"deviceName\": \"iPhone 6\", \"bundelId\": \"com.app.foo\", \"automationName\": \"XCUITest\", \"autoWebview\": false, \"newCommandTimeout\": 3600, \"platformVersion\": \"11.2\", \"fullReset\": false, \"noReset\": true, \"locationServicesEnabled\": true, \"locationServicesAuthorized\": true, \"calendarAccessAuthorized\": true}}}}'--steps",
"android": "codeceptjs run -c codecept.conf.js --override '{\"helpers\": {\"Appium\": {\"app\": \"<path_apk>/<name_apk>.apk\", \"platform\": \" Android\", \"device\": \"<code_your_device>\", \"desiredCapabilities\": {\"platformVersion\": \"<version_your_android>\", \"platformName\": \"Android\", \"deviceName\": \"Anyname\", \"appPackage\": \"your_appPackage>\", \"appActivity\": \"<your_appActivity>\"}}}}'--steps"
}
```

Be sure to comment out the helpers in the `codecept.conf.js` file.

To run across platforms run the command with the `&` operator: `npm run web & npm run ios`

Run Web Only: `npm run web`

Run only Android: `npm run android`

Run web iOS: `npm run ios`

I hope that solves your problem. Good luck o/

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot run two helpers with (partially) same API in one time.
One run for one helper.

You can run it parallel in 2 different parallel jobs, for example in CI jobs.

And one more. You should not to set `Appium` in `WebDriver` - they are 2 different helpers. Helpers are defined in one level

```
helpers: {
 WebDriver: {
   ...
 },
 REST: {
   ...
 }
},..
```

But this does not work for similar helpers (with similar API) in one config (WebDriver/Appium/Puppeteer/others).
You should use 2 configs: one for Appium and one for WebDriver.